# HTTP Status 404 error in the jsp, netbeans

Tags: jsp, servlets, netbeans

I'm new to jsp. When i am running jsp file in netbeans and submit http 404 error coming.

This is the from header that i used,

```
 <form method="POST" action="/test.java">
```

My file hierachy in the netbeans is,

```
Test

   Web Pages

      index.jsp

   Source Packages

      <default package>

      test.java
```

The link that I gave to the action is correct or wrong?

I'm using jdk 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you are doing is wrong. I guess you want to submit this form to a Servlet(test.java).

First you have to make sure that test.java (btw this is not a proper convention in java for a class name, it should start with an uppercase letter) is actually a servlet by extending the HttpServlet class, and implementing the required methods (`doGet()` and/or `doPost()` ...). More Info [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

Then you have to map this Servlet in the web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.java</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then submit the form to the `url-pattern` of the servlet assigned above. In this example your form should look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/Test">
```

Note: You can use the IDE's servlet wizard to automate this functionality, but Its always better to know also how things work internally.

You can check also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info to see how servlets work

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans, when you right click to create a new Servlet, the wizard begins, in the window where you are asked to enter "Class name", "Servlet name" and "URL Pattern(s)", leave the Class name, but change the Servlet name (so the URL Pattern will be the Servlet name with slash). Now all you have to do is to call your servlet using the Servlet name (the one we changed), not the Class name, and don't use the slash! Example: the wizard begins, you name your servlet AAA, in the next window you leave the "Class name" AAA, but the "Servlet name" is BBB, and the "URL Pattern(s)" /BBB, now you can call your servlet using the name BBB, not AAA, and not /BBB.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be due to inappropriate jdk used. Or netbeans using inappropriate jdk location.i.e.low level jdk.Solution can be uninstall netbeans and then install again and while setup provide accurate jdk (1.8,etc)path.